# How could I route to the /Home/Index action regardless of the URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am looking for a way to route all traffic to my Home controller and to the Index action, regardless of the URL they use to arrive at my site.

As long as they are using www.MyDomain.com, a user visiting www.MyDomain.com/Controller1/Action1 would need to all be routed to the same action as a user visiting www.MyDomain.com/Controller2/Action3/ID6

I can redirect each one of these manually but some of the URL's may be dynamically generated and therefore I need to learn how to catch all and redirect.

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: Have a look at the [URL Rewrite tool in IIS Manager](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/08/iis-7-redirect-domaincom-to.html).  This is (imo) the best way to re-route incoming traffic.  If you use the route mapping in Global, you may be likely to screw up the internal routing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting your routes, you may try defining a default route as the **last** route definition

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{*any}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was something like that but couldn't find any reference material on it.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a file `Global.asax.cs` in root of your solution where logic for routing is written, modify the logic according to your requirement.