# ASP.NET routing. Default page

Tags: asp.net, routes

I am using routing in my ASP.NET application.

What I want to do, if user enters some wrong url, he should be redirected to pagenotfound.aspx

Examples :

```
http://mysite/product/   //<- OK. Goes to all products

http://mysite/product/ipad   //<- OK. Goes to ipad product

http://mysite/somerandomstuff/   //<- NOT OK!! This one should go to pagenotfound.aspx Now I`m getting error:

 Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 The resource cannot be found.
```

My code is:

```
//works ok
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "products-all",             
    "product",            
    "~/products.aspx"); 

    //works ok
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "products-category",             
    "product/{category}",            
    "~/product.aspx"); 

//does not work!!!
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "pagenotfound",             
    "",          // <-- what should be here????  
    "~/pagenotfound.aspx");
```

Thank you

Comment: maybe this can be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/14586192/1236044

Comment: this article explain in detail about how to implement pagenotfound [custom page not found](http://www.ssidelnikov.ru/en/2011/09/asp-net-custom-error-404-page/)